# Calendar & Contacts - How to Mark All as Read

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2013, contacts

In Outlook 2013, the folder view is showing my Calendar and Contacts with a number to the right of it. I assume this means there are "unread" items in Calendar and Contacts. Perhaps my assumption is wrong on what these numbers are, but I want the numbers to be hidden. How do I do this?

[image: Calendar count?]

Comment: Try [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/unread-contacts-in-outlook-2010/0564ce2d-5392-479d-a867-6b78362d6e54). If not, are you on exchange?

Comment: You had the right idea... @TECHIE007 was able to provide the answer that worked in batch. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- In Outlook, switch to the "Mail" or "Folder" view, and click on your Inbox.
- Click on the magnifying glass at the right end of the search bar.

When you do that, it brings up a new ribbon of Search Tools.

- Click on the "*Search Tools*" Icon (wrench and hammer) and then to *Advanced Find* under the drop down menu.
- Make sure the drop downs are set to "*Appointments and Meetings*" in "*Calendar*".
- Click on the *More Choices* tab, and you will see an option "*Only Items that are*".
- Click that drop down, and select "*Unread*" and put a check mark in the box next to it.
- Click "Find Now".

The unread calendar items will be listed below.

- Click one of the listed appointments and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select All the appointments listed.
- Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to mark them all as read.

If the Ctrl+Q doesn't work for some reason, an alternative is to (after selecting all found messages via CTRL+A):

- Press the enter key.
- There will be a warning that this might take a long time, but just click continue.

All the unread calendar items will now open.

- Once all items are open, right click the Outlook icon on the task bar and select "Close all Windows".

All the open calendar items and outlook itself will now close.  Next time you open Outlook, all there will not be any unread calendar items.

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2c910892-b191-446e-813b-d7d3c7dd1167/mark-all-as-read-in-outlook-2010-calendar-and-tasks?forum=outlook)

Comment: The `Ctrl`+`A` then `Ctrl`+`Q` then worked. It is not obvious since Unread items are not in bold, so I had to go back to main view to see that the count next to each folder disappeared.

Comment: For my `Calendar [349]` notice how the number count is not in bold. Even after Techie007's answer, I had to right click on Calendar, go to Properties, and change the radio box so unread count is selected. Just an adjunct answer if anyone else runs into an incomplete solution: http://i.stack.imgur.com/RXa8e.png

Comment: be aware that if the elements are in a shared calendar it will not show up when you search _in "Calendar"_, you may need to specify the location of that shared calendar.

Answer (score 4):

In the search bar, type "read:no" and it will bring up all Outlook items that are unread.

Comment: this is not an answer as OP is trying to hide the number of unread items it shows next to folder not unread them

Comment: @pun: if outlook had been somewhat user-friendly, this would actually have been a brilliant first part of an answer. As one of the prerequisites to being able to mark an element as unread, is to find that element! but unfortunately although outlook is able to list calendar elements silmilarly to how it lists emails, it is not able to mark them as unread in the same way. 

Comment: @clhy --it was actually the answer I was hoping to find, so it makes sense to me that it is here!