# Disable unread count for calendars?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

How can I completely disable the Unread Count for calendars?

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: If it's anything like Outlook 2013 and earlier, you can't.  It's either 'Unread', or 'Total count', no other option.  Have you checked the properties of the folder to see which related options are available?

Comment: Those are the two options, but they are both grayed out.  As you implied, neither are what I want.  An unread count is ignorant in this context.

Comment: Kind of odd they are greyed out, even though it's a calendar entry.  Regardless of that though, it's one or the other; unless someone comes up with a hack.

Comment: It wouldn't be so bad if I could right-click and "Mark All As Read" like you can on an email folder.  Why would anyone even want to see an unread count of meetings?  Like, I can't even wrap my brain around it.  This particular 1 meeting is literally in 2 months.  I had to FIND it to "read" it.  /rant

Comment: p.s. Added a screenshot of the properties.

Comment: Oh it's in the 'Public Folders', at least that explains why those options are greyed out. "Why would anyone even want to see an unread count of meetings?"  If someone else puts a meeting on your calendar, you'll know there's a new appointment.  PS: in case you haven't seen this other SU question: [Calendar & Contacts - How to Mark All as Read](https://superuser.com/questions/818797/outlook-2013-calendar-contacts-how-to-mark-all-as-read)

Comment: I tried the CTRL+A, CTRL+Q shortcut from the "List" view before posting here.  CTRL+Q did nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Microsoft Outlook, by default the unread item count for public folders is not displayed. However, once the public folder is added to Public Folder Favorites, the unread item count will be turned on. From the image, it looks the calendar is in your Public Folder Favorites, correct? try remove it from favorites and see whether the issue continues. Otherwise, you'll need to have move higher permission on the public folder calendar to turn on/off the unread item count.

See [How to display the unread item count for public folders in Outlook](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/outlooking/2016/09/28/how-to-display-the-unread-item-count-for-public-folders-in-outlook/) for more details.